# Choppy/laggy video on HDMI out

Tags: video, hdmi

Whenever I play video from my device on my TV via a mini-HDMI to HDMI cable, the video appears slightly laggy/choppy on my TV. Playing the video on the laptop itself is completely fine.

Its local media, the CPU usage is minimal during playback so I don't think its a system resources issue. Like i said, it plays fine on the laptop screen.

Since I don't know alot about all the different advanced settings, I was wondering if anyone had any ideas for trying to fix this.

I've tried in both desktop extension mode and with the laptop only displaying on the TV. I have the latest drivers for everything.

Specs of the machine are:

Windows 8.1 (full version - not RT)
Atom Quad Core processor (Z3770 to be exact)
2GB RAM
Intel HD graphics

Someone said it could be to do with framerates but didn't give any more information than that.

Its almost like there are frames missing, if that makes sense

Comment: I'm having the same issue on a laptop with Intel graphics. The funny thing is it worked fine until a driver update two months ago; since that update, it's been extremely laggy. Video plays fine with sound disabled, but sound over HDMI causes lag.

Answer (score 5):

I have had a video jitter / choppy video playback when my laptop was projecting it's screen to my TV via HDMI for several months. This morning I managed to fix it. A few months ago I had raised the display resolution being projected over the HDMI cable to 1920x1280 so the desktop would display completely on my TV, without being cropped. This had caused video to play jittery, so when I rolled back the resolution to 1280×720, video became smooth again.

Note, the HDMI Digital Display setting in the Display properties was only available for adjusting once the HDMI cable had been plugged in. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

been having this issue and couldnt figure it out - eventually i checked the refresh rate of my TV under the intel graphics properties - it defaulted to 29, set it to 60p HZ and instantly fixed the issue!!

For some reason intel "sees" TV and assumes its an old style TV! mine was a 48 Samsung LED..

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by changing the display option from duplicate to extend, then just dragging the video onto the TV. Haven’t had an issue since.

Comment: Strangely enough, this solved the problem for me as well. Would like to know more about _why_ it occurred in the first place. It seems like a refresh rate mismatch or something.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have had the same issue and I  change the the scale of the display in intel graphics command center to Maintain Display Scaling and right away the issue was resolved. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your graphics card is integrated, it will cause **severe** lag unless, as you do, it carries extra GRAM. As it is, you need a discrete or dedicated card (or two, optimally) to output into a large, second screen.

Comment: I only ever display on one device (either the laptop or the external TV). Both with the same resolution. I highly doubt this is a resource issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it. Try this:

1. Assuming you are on Win 10, right click on the desktop.
2. Click "Display settings".
3. Scroll to the very bottom, click "Graphics settings".
4. Turn on "Hardware-Accelerated GPU scheduling".

Answer (score 0):

I disabled Motion Plus option and it worked for me. None of given advices here worked on my tv.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue. Uninstalling and reinstalling the Intel Audio adapter fixed it. All I had to do was uninstall it from Device Manager and after reboot Windows reinstalled the driver automatically. Usually an annoying feature, but it worked perfectly so I did not need to reinstall manually. I recommend manual reinstall if the autoreinstall does not work.